# Create git tag only if it maches a pattern

Tags: regex, git, tags

We have a script that takes the last tag from our git repository and parses it in order to create the version number.

In order to do so, the tag must have a defined pattern (vX.Y.Z).

Is it possible to avoid to create a tag that does not match a specific pattern, in order to avoid distraction errors?

Comment: On which platform do you run you git instance ? Github, Gitlab, personnal server?

Comment: It's our work server, running Ubuntu, but I'd like to check name on my local PC, using windows even if I can run linux commands in git bash.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can create a git alias of `tag` command to override/replace original tag command. In alias, you check the tag name.

See [here](https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases) for more details about git alias.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005513/pass-an-argument-to-a-git-alias-command) for how to pass argument to git alias.

UPDATE:

After some investigation, as [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538774/is-it-possible-to-override-git-command-by-git-alias), you can not override git command, but in that post, provide some methods to bypass this restriction.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that you can't do it *easily*. Here are the places that I've looked:

1. [2.6 Git Basics - Tagging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging)
2. [git-tag man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag)
3. [git-verify-tag man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-verify-tag)
4. [git-config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)

There is not a single mention on how/what to do to force tag format. I know that Gitlab provides [git hooks](http://docs.gitlab.com/ee/git_hooks/git_hooks.html) to force commit message format.

---

You can take a look at [How do I react to new tags in git hooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809910/how-do-i-react-to-new-tags-in-git-hooks) and [Is there a way to check that a git tag matches the content of the corresponding commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418071/is-there-a-way-to-check-that-a-git-tag-matches-the-content-of-the-corresponding)