# Git hook to check tag name

Tags: git, hook

Is there any git hook that checks the name or string of a new git tag, potentially even prior to "committing" the new tag (e.g. something like pre-commit, but for tags)? Purpose of my question is that I want to prohibit git tag names in the format of "abc" or "v1.2.3". Git tag names should always strictly follow to the "1.2.3" syntax.

Comment: At the client side it should be pre-push hook. At the server side it should be pre-receive  or update hook. Something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/5810488/7976758 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/8444966/7976758

Comment: @phd: Thanks for your comment. I am indeed looking for a client side solution. I was also considering pre-push hook. However, the downside of the approach is that it basically allows stating a wrong tag name in the first stage. I am looking for an approach that even prohibits "wrong" tag names on client side.

Comment: Then write a shell wrapper or a git alias for `git tag` — a script that will check the name and then call `git tag "$@"`. I cannot think of any other way. There are certainly no client-side hooks for tags.

Comment: Thanks, this is a valid answer. By the way, I do not understand the downgrade of my questions. Is this really that invalid?

Comment: Not my downvote. The question is certainly valid.

Comment: Feel free to state your comment as the official answer. I will accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insist on a hook at the client side it should be pre-push hook. At the server side it should be pre-receive or update hook. Something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/5810488/7976758 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/8444966/7976758.

There are certainly no client-side hooks for tags. To check tag names without hooks at the tag creation time write a shell wrapper or a git alias for `git tag` — a script that will check the name and then call `git tag "$@"`.

Comment: An example pre-push hook which deals with checking version tags can be found at https://gist.github.com/gggeek/d1a30095710fdf5c228efdfc2f8af934 . It does not enforce tag structure, but checks that source code matches the last tag looking like a version number. It should not be too hard to make fit for purpose.