# Git hook for diff sqlite table

Tags: git, sqlite, githooks

I have a Sqlite db in a Git repository. Today I wanted to do a diff of a view in two different commits. I did it this way:

```
$ sqlite3 -list file.sqlite "SELECT * FROM contact_list_detailed" >/tmp/newlist
$ git checkout 51c24d13c file.sqlite
$ sqlite3 -list file.sqlite "SELECT * FROM contact_list_detailed" >/tmp/oldlist
$ git checkout -- file.sqlite
$ diff /tmp/oldlist /tmp/newlist
```

It works and I could script it if I want. But are there any "nice" ways of doing this with hooks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use `HEAD` and `HEAD^` to access the previous and current revisions; see [git post-commit hook - script on committed files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616648/git-post-commit-hook-script-on-committed-files) for an example.

Use [`git show`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show.html) to extract files to a temporary directory without overwriting the working copy.

---

I wouldn't store binary files in `git` unless absolutely necessary.
You can avoid many hassles if you create a text file of SQL commands with `sqlite3 file.sqlite .dump` and put *that* into git, having the binary database only as a generated file.
(But then you have to care about regenerating the SQL file when necessary.)

Comment: Could I put my db-file into the .gitignore file and then use a pre-commit-hook to dump the contents and to a file that I add to my git repo? And then I use some kind of pre-pull-hook to create the sqlite binary file from this dumped content?

Comment: Yes (but I guess you want `post-checkout`).

Comment: What you say really makes sense and I guess this really is the right way of doing things. I don't have time to really implement this now. But I mark you answer as accepted.

Comment: @NiclasNilsson replying to a very old treat, but have you been able to make it work? If so it would be nice if you could include the steps

Answer (score 42):

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150602052210/http://ongardie.net/blog/sqlite-in-git) is how to use git's `textconv` feature for showing diffs between versions of the sqlite file.  It just does a dump, so it may not be super efficient for large databases.  No hook necessary.

That link seems to be no longer available, so I'm using the the archived version instead.

The gist of it is, in the git attributes file (`.gitattributes`, or `.git/info/attributes`), add a pattern match to force sqlite3 diffs (assuming your database files have the extension `.sqlite3`):

```
*.sqlite3 diff=sqlite3
```

Then in your git config file (`~/.gitconfig` or `.git/config`):

```
[diff "sqlite3"]
    binary = true
    textconv = "echo .dump | sqlite3"
```

If you just want to track schema changes, use `.schema` instead of `.dump`.

Comment: I guess it's just good practice to save it in text format anyway. But this is a nice solution nerver the less. +1

Comment: I had to use this `textconv = "f(){ sqlite3 -batch \"$1\" .dump; }; f"`.

Answer (score 6):

In case one really wants to track the binary database files in git there are some problems.
Since sqlite databases might differ without the data stored within having changed the output of `git status` is not really helpful to determine if one should commit and `git diff` does only show something like `Binary files a/foo.sql and b/foo.sql differ`.
To get proper output from `git diff` there are basically two approaches to compare respective files:

1. Use `textconv` to convert files to plain text as shown in the answer by [Biran Minton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21789167/1905491).
2. Set up a custom diff application that is able to directly create diffs.

I'll outline the second approach below using `sqldiff` that comes with sqlite.
As with the `textconv` approach one needs to change the attributes and config files.

*attributes:*

```
*.sql* diff=sqldiff
```

*config:*

```
[diff "sqldiff"]
    command = gitsqldiff
```

The `gitsqldiff` string above refers to a wrapper script that is required to arrange the parameters given by git for consumption by `sqldiff`.
It has to be executable and reachable via the `PATH` environment variable (putting it in `~/bin` should be fine).
Because (as of now) the exit value of `sqldiff` is always 0 and thus rather useless we have to check what it prints to give the user feedback - especially in the case nothing in the database has changed according to `sqldiff` which produces no output at all.
To do so and show the complete output to the user we use a [trick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43536/41065) that redirects the output to an additional file descriptor and `stdout` via `tee`.

`gitsqldiff`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
echo "$1:"

# Duplicate sqldiff's output for consumption by wc and stdout.
# This enables us to check for an empty output but still see
# sqldiffs messages if there are any.
sqldiff "$2" "$5" 2>&1 | {
    tee /dev/fd/3 |
        if [ $(wc -c) -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "  nothing changed according to sqldiff"
        fi
} 3>&1
```

This of course does not make sql files first-class citizens in a git repository but might facilitate a workflow that works nevertheless.